# Android Studio 0.2.1 ERROR

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-studio, build-error

I have recently updated Android Studio to version 0.2.1, only to find myself in a difficult sitation yet again.
This time the compiler says: "Abnormal build process termination: 
Error: Could not find or load main class Files"!

This is what my screen looks like: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-srUlUCSl2iI/Ue0BqrXJgCI/AAAAAAAAARw/4UZ0IExLWRk/w958-h766-no/Untitled.jpg

Comment: check this : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=57820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. My solution was to right click main and and mark it as source root